# I want to display an alert saying "passwords are not matching" instead of res.send("passwords are not matching")

Tags: javascript, html, express

Currently in my registration form when the user enters different texts in the 'password' and 'confirm password' fields, he gets "passwords are not matching" on a new page.
Like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXkyx.png

But I want to display an alert saying "Passwords are not matching". What changes should I make in my code to achieve this?

**HTML code of registration form**

```
<form action="/register" id="RegForm" method = "POST">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
         <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword">
         <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Create account"/>
         <a class="loginAnchor" href="/">Already a user? Sign up</a>
</form>
```

**Express.js code**

```
app.post("/register", async (req,res) =>{
    try{
        const password = req.body.password;
        const cpassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
        if(password === cpassword){
            const registerEmployee = new Register({
                username : req.body.username,
                email : req.body.email,
                password : password,
                confirmPassword : cpassword
            })
            const registered = await registerEmployee.save();
            res.status(201).render("login");
        }
        else{
            //I want to display the message "Passwords not matching" in an alert.
            res.send("Passwords are not matching");
        }
    }catch(error){
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }
})
```

Comment: The overload you are using for `res.send` infers that you are sending a `string` response and thus automatically appends the `text/html` content-type, which your browser picks up as a webpage. If you would send a object such as `res.send({ message: 'Passwords are not matching' })`, you would instead receive a JSON response with your message.

Comment: If you want the user to load a blank page with an alert, then that's easy, just change your res.send to be an alert inside a script tag.  However, you probably want the form to still be visible under your alert, which is a different story.  For that, you'd need to post your form asynchronously from the first page, using ajax or similar.

Comment: On a side node, your inputs are missing labels, which is a considerable usability issue. Placeholders are no replacement for labels. You might also consider using `autocomplete="new-password"` on your password fields to allow browsers to generate secure passwords, bumping up usability and accessibility of your form.

Comment: Try: alert(), for example alert("Passwords are not mathching")